# In drag and drop selecting an item from list it reappears again on search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, filter

I have a dnd selection tab with search functionality to filter the items available. Once an item is selected from draggable section it should be removed from that section and dropped to the droppable section and vice versa.
The link to my code is https://codesandbox.io/s/dnd-search-select-sort-xfdtn
When an item say "Apple" is selected it is going to the droppable section but when I search for "Apple" again in the draggable section search bar it reappears again and I can again move that to the droppable section which should not be the case. Once it is selected it should not appear again on the list. Below is the corresponding code.

```
import React from "react";
import { Icon, Col, Input, Card, Tooltip, Tabs } from "antd";
import "ant-design-draggable-modal/dist/index.css";
import { Scrollbars } from "react-custom-scrollbars";
import Fuse from "fuse.js";

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const { Search } = Input;
const items = [
  {
    values: ["false", "true"],
    cleanTitle: "Apple",
    columnName: "apple",
    type: "fruit"
  },
  {
    values: ["false", "true"],
    cleanTitle: "Mango",
    columnName: "mango",
    type: "fruit"
  },
  {
    values: ["false", "true"],
    cleanTitle: "Berry",
    columnName: "berry",
    type: "fruit"
  },
  {
    values: ["false", "true"],
    cleanTitle: "Orange",
    columnName: "orange",
    type: "fruit"
  },
  {
    values: ["false", "true"],
    cleanTitle: "Litchi",
    columnName: "litchi",
    type: "fruit"
  },
  {
    values: ["false", "true"],
    cleanTitle: "Pineapple",
    columnName: "pineapple",
    type: "fruit"
  }
];
class ItemSelection extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible: true,
    items: items,
    selected: [],
    fuzzySearcher: new Fuse(items, { keys: ["cleanTitle"] })
  };

  handleItemSelect = selectedSegmentIndex => {
    let { items, selected } = this.state;
    const [removed] = items.splice(selectedSegmentIndex, 1);
    selected.splice(selected.length, 0, removed);
    this.setState({ items, selected });
  };
  handleItemUnselect = unselectedSegmentIndex => {
    let { items, selected } = this.state;
    const [removed] = selected.splice(unselectedSegmentIndex, 1);
    items.splice(items.length, 0, removed);
    this.setState({ items, selected });
  };
  handleItemUnselect = (index, dir) => {
    let { selected } = this.state;
    selected.splice(index, 0, selected.splice(index + dir, 1)[0]);
    this.setState({ selected });
  };
  handleItemSearch = searchText => {
    searchText !== "" &&
      this.setState({ items: this.state.fuzzySearcher.search(searchText) });
  };
  handleItemMove = (index, dir) => {
    let { selected } = this.state;
    selected.splice(index, 0, selected.splice(index + dir, 1)[0]);
    this.setState({ selected, defaultChanged: true });
  };
  render() {
    const { tabKey } = this.props;
    return (
      <Tabs type="card" defaultActiveKey={tabKey}>
        <TabPane tab="Select Items" key="2">
          <div className="item-dnd">
            <Col span={12}>
              <Card className="droppable-item-card" title="Available items">
                <Search
                  className="search-fuzzy-item"
                  allowClear={true}
                  placeholder="Search for a fruit"
                  onChange={e => this.handleItemSearch(e.target.value)}
                />
                <div className="droppable-item-left">
                  <Scrollbars style={{ height: 300 }}>
                    {this.state.items &&
                      this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
                        <Col span={24} key={item.columnName}>
                          <div
                            className="draggable-item"
                            key={`source-${index}`}
                          >
                            {item.cleanTitle}
                            <Tooltip
                              placement="bottom"
                              title={<span>Select</span>}
                            >
                              <span
                                className={
                                  this.state.selected.length < 4
                                    ? "item-move-icon-right"
                                    : "item-move-icon-right-disabled"
                                }
                              >
                                <Icon
                                  type="caret-right"
                                  onClick={() => {
                                    this.state.selected.length < 4
                                      ? this.handleItemSelect(index)
                                      : null;
                                  }}
                                />
                              </span>
                            </Tooltip>
                          </div>
                        </Col>
                      ))}
                  </Scrollbars>
                </div>
              </Card>
            </Col>
            <Col span={12}>
              <Card
                className="droppable-item-card"
                title={`Selected Items (${this.state.selected.length})`}
              >
                <div className="droppable-item-right">
                  {this.state.selected.map((item, index) => (
                    <div className="draggable-item" key={`target-${index}`}>
                      <Tooltip
                        placement="bottom"
                        title={<span>Un-select</span>}
                      >
                        <span className="item-move-icon-left">
                          <Icon
                            type="caret-left"
                            onClick={() => {
                              this.handleItemUnselect(index);
                            }}
                          />
                        </span>
                      </Tooltip>
                      {item.cleanTitle}
                      <span className="item-move-icon-right">
                        {index > 0 && (
                          <Icon
                            type="caret-up"
                            onClick={() => {
                              this.handleItemMove(index - 1, 1);
                            }}
                          />
                        )}
                        {index < this.state.selected.length - 1 && (
                          <Icon
                            type="caret-down"
                            onClick={() => {
                              this.handleItemMove(index + 1, -1);
                            }}
                          />
                        )}
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </div>
        </TabPane>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}

export default ItemSelection;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your state you create `Fuse` instance once with full list of `items`. In your `handleItemSearch` you always search against full list of `items`. Hence the issue.

**To solve the issue**, create fresh instance of `Fuse` in your `handleItemSearch`

```js
handleItemSearch = searchText => {
    // this.setState({ items: this.state.fuzzySearcher.search(searchText) }); //<--- don't do this

    this.setState(({items}) => ({ items: new Fuse(items, { keys: ["cleanTitle"] }).search(searchText) }));
  };
```

[Working demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dnd-search-select-sort-fwmz2)